# Removing User Object's Status Code property

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Microsoft graph User object (user) which contains several user properties. I am looking to delete the StatusCode property, however it is not appearing as a property when using (user.StatusCode). However, other properties such as user.Country is appearing. Is there a way delete the StatusCode?

[Image of status code property pulled from User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUTA7.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, `statusCode` is not the property of User object. You could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) about user Properties. I also try to get the User object with graph API, and it returns without this property.

[image]

`statusCode` is always used for the HTTP response. If you call the Graph API with HTTP, it may occur to show you the status of response. So I recommend you to use **SDK**.

*For example, when [getting a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request):*

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
User user = await graphClient.Users["user-object-id"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work